# javascript checkbox function is not working perfectly

Tags: javascript

after i click on checkbox for unchecking it it is not jumping on else condition. alert ('uncheck') condition in codeigniter please help me.
i cant  switch between checked and unchecked condition.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var ckbox = $("input[name='checkbox']");
//var chkId = '';
$('input').on('click', function() {

if (ckbox.is(':checked')) {
  $("input[name='checkbox']:checked").each ( function() {
    chkId = $(this).val() + ",";
    //chkId = chkId.slice(0, -1);
  });

  var id = $(this).val();
  var days= $('#days').attr('value');
  //var checked=1;
  var r = confirm("do you want to continue")

   if (r==true) {

    window.location= url+"client/home/auto_renew?id="+id+"/"+days+"/checked";

   } else {

    alert('ok');

   }


} else {
    alert('uncheck');
    window.location= url+"client/home/auto_renew?id="+id+"/"+days+"/unchecked";
}     
           });
    });     

   for html   

   <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="<?php echo $data->id; ?>" checked>
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug the function?

Comment: i have.. bt i cant switch between checked or unchecked properly once it set checked it remains checked for other checkbox also

Comment: I have tried your code using JSfiddle and it's working. What's the issue here? https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/923214/

Comment: You might be forcing it in some other piece of code. put the full code here if this is not the whole code